# oracle.jdbc.driver in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am adding a feature to existing app that I imported into Eclipse.  I am getting a ton of errors within Eclipse that say import to oracle is unresolved:

```
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes;
```

Obviously this app has been working, but my path is apparently wrong.  Where is the common place oracle drivers are installed?

Comment: did had a jdbc driver added to Eclipse classpath

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the driver is usually installed, since the projects I use with this driver usually include the library.  However, I have had some success with JarScan:

http://www.inetfeedback.com/jarscan/

It will sometimes crash if you try to scan your entire hard drive, but if you narrow the scope a little bit (e.g. Program Files), you might turn something up.

Answer (score 0):

Check the classpath of your project and make sure that there are no build path errors. You can do this by right clicking on your project and going to `Java Build Path` there.

You can also find any build path errors in your project listed under the `Problems` view. Just identify the one corresponding to your project.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be even more better if you download the driver manually as the default package is usually a little out of date.

The driver's archive usually contains:

1. Source code for debugging (usually zip file)
2. Java Doc package (usually zip file)
3. Binary package (usually jar file)

You should unzip the driver to your favorite folder and register the binary file as your library (and adding it to your classpath by that).

[Here is a good point to learn even more](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project%27s_classpath?)